# Django:int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

This may be  same be an alreday asked **error** but in my case error is same but a **different question**,
Hi every one i have already writtem one django apllication in which i have a set of templates they are

1. Login.html
2. Logout.html
3. dashboards.html

After authentication in login form user will be forwarded to dashboards.html.
My question is if the user tries directly **dashboards.html** without going through **login page**, then i am getting this error. Instead of this i want to show user login.html if he's trying to access dashboards.html directly. thanks in advance.

my views.py looks like

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from ow_dashboard.models import Dashboard
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def custom_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboards')        
    return login(request, 'login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm)

def custom_logout(request):
    return logout(request, next_page='/')

def user(request):
    groups = request.user.groups.all()
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        groups = []
    dashboards = Dashboard.objects.filter(owner=groups)

    context = {
        'user': request.user,
        'groups': groups,
        'dashboards': dashboards,
    }
    return render_to_response('registration/dashboards.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# Create your views here.
```

and dashboards.html is like

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>*OXI-KIBANA*</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #eee; height:60px;">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:1%">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="http://www.mpowersoft.com/"><img src="{% static "bootstrap/css/logo4.png" %}" alt="MPOWER"/></a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-right:4%;"><span style="margin-left:125%; ">
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}

    {{ user.first_name }}
       {{ request.user.username }}</span>
{% elseif user.is_anonymous%}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please <a href="login.html">log in</a>.</p>
{% endif %}</div>
<div >
<span style="margin-left:9%;">
<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">sign out</button></a></span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="background-color: #eee; width:19%; height:968%; margin-top:10px;">
<div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color: #eee;">Dashboards
{% for Dashboard in dashboards %}
<strong><a href="#">{{ Dashboard.d_name }}</a><strong>
{% endfor %}
</div>  
</div>



<div class="right-contain" style="background-color: #eee; margin-top:-581px; margin-left:18%; width:83%; height:968%;">
kibana
</div>


<div class="row" style="background-color: #eee;  margin-top:3px;"><marquee>Footer</marquee>

</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    url(r'^dashboards/$', 'ow_dashboard.views.user'),
)
```

Comment: Is your dashboards view have `login_required` decorators ?

Comment: @raja, can u please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its same as same daniel said. u can run following code to get the result.

```html
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def user(request):
    groups = request.user.groups.all()
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        groups = []
    dashboards = Dashboard.objects.filter(owner=groups)

    context = {
        'user': request.user,
        'groups': groups,
        'dashboards': dashboards,
    }
    return render_to_response('test2.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: its working but  can i use the same view or can i refer same view from different urls

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be asking about your actual problem. The error you mention is because you seem to be explicitly setting `groups` to an empty list if the user is anonymous. But you are also quite clear what you actually want to happen, which is to send the user to a login page. So why didn't you ask about that?

As Raja says, the solution to *that* problem is to put a `@login_required` decorator on the view.